# Disable horizontal scroll on mobile devices

Tags: php, css

My website is ********

Horizontal scroll only shows on mobile devices, not even on desktop with mobile resolution.

I have tried overflow-x:hidden, width: 100% on body and html

Comment: Try removing `user-scalable=no` from your `<meta name="viewport"/>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this style**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    overflow-x: hidden!important;
  }
}
```